# Need help to define a query, where I am trying to get data from 3 different tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

- **Mattress:**
  id (PK), idUser(FK) healthSystemName, building, floor, room, bed, reference
- **Patient:**
  id (PK), idMattress(FK), idUSer(FK), name, surname, gender, birthdate, medicalRecordNumber, visitrRecordNumber, strees, city, postalCode, country, maxPressureTolerance
- **PressureMap:**
  id (PK), idMattress(FK), pressureData, maxPressure, presence, bodyPosition, created_at, updated_at

I would like to know the query I need to use to get the following view:

*Patient.name, Patient.surname, Patient.medicalRecordNumber, Patient.visitRecordNumber, Mattress.room, Mattress.id, PressureMap.pressureData (**only the latest by created_at**), PressureMap.presence*

- If the Mattress is empty, it should be shown in this view with the patient and the pressureMap data = NULL

Right now, I have the following query:

```
SELECT p.name
     , p.surname
     , p.medicalRecordNumber
     , p.visitRecordNumber
     , m.room
     , m.id mattressID 
  FROM mattress m
  LEFT 
  JOIN patient p
    on p.idMattress = m.id
```

where I group as I need the table mattress and the table patient but I don't know how to add the pressureMap data with only the last entry. So, I get the green data and I need to know how to add the yellow one.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Reading the documentation of [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) can be a good start.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: SELECT patient.name, patient.surname, patient.medicalRecordNumber, patient.visitRecordNumber, mattress.room, mattress.id FROM `mattress` LEFT JOIN `patient` on patient.idMattress = mattress.id

Comment: please add your query to the question itself (using the "edit" button), and then explain what problem you're having - e.g. does it give you an error, or it returns unexpected results? In either case, show us the output. For additional clarity, give an example of what the source data looks like, and what results you want to get from the query.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to solve it with Laravel Query builder.

```
$latestPressureMap = DB::table('pressuremap')
        ->select('idMattress', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as last_pressureMap_created_at'), 'presence', 'maxPressure')
        ->groupBy('idMattress');

    $mattress = DB::table('mattress')
        ->leftJoinSub($latestPressureMap, 'latest_pressureMap', function ($join) {
            $join->on('mattress.id', '=', 'latest_pressureMap.idMattress');
        })
        ->leftJoin("patient","mattress.id","=","patient.idMattress")
        ->select("patient.id", "patient.name", "patient.surname", "patient.medicalRecordNumber", "patient.visitRecordNumber", "mattress.id", "mattress.healthSystemName","mattress.building","mattress.floor","mattress.room", "mattress.bed", "patient.gender", "latest_pressureMap.presence", "latest_pressureMap.last_pressureMap_created_at","latest_pressureMap.maxPressure")
        ->where('mattress.idUser', '=', $id)
        ->get();

    return view('dashboard',['mattress' => $mattress]);
```